# How to export xls when calling rails from javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, excel

I am trying to trigger an excelsheet download via a javascript call.
When I use a button link_to to call the rails action, it works fine.
But when I call the rails action via js script (which I want to do) I get the same rendered message in the log but the excel does not download.
I presume this is something to do with the ajax/background task call but I can't figure it out. Any idea how to get the javascript approach to work?

Rails Action:

```
def goal_designer_spreadsheet
  @format = params[:format]
  logger.debug "\nformat = #{@format} \n"
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html 
    xls_filename = "Excel_file__abc.xls"
    format.xls {headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=\"#{xls_filename}\"" }
  end
end
```

2 buttons: 1 triggers a JS call (not working), one direct to rails (working):

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="goal_download_list">Download this Plan (.xls) javascript</button>

<%= link_to "Download this Plan (.xls) rails", plan_goal_designer_spreadsheet_path(format: "xls"), :id => "", :class => "btn btn-small btn-primary" %>
```

Javascript call:

```
if ( trigger_object.id.match(/goal_download_list/) ) {
  $.ajax({
    type:  'get',       
    url:   "/plan/goal_designer_spreadsheet",
    data: { 
      "format":   "xls"
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus) {
    }      
  });  
}
```

Output log: similar in both cases, but in case of JS call, no xls downloads:

```
Rendered plan/goal_designer_spreadsheet.xls.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 344ms (Views: 339.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download File Using Javascript/jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery)

Comment: Probably this answer will help http://stackoverflow.com/a/23013574/7362128

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's better to make a redirect:

```
window.open("plan/goal_designer_spreadsheet.xls", "_blank");
```

Comment: The route from routes.rb:    get 'plan/goal_designer_spreadsheet'.      I made your changes re: not sending the format and got the same result: I get a render complete message in the log, but no downloaded file.

Comment: Thanks Victor. This worked great. I just had to remove the "plan/" and pass parameters at the end of the string:  `url_string = "goal_designer_spreadsheet.xls?sb="+start_balance`, `window.open(url_string, "_blank");`

Comment: Note these lines were instead of the entire $.ajax call I had at the start.

Comment: Great, I'm glad to help.

Comment: @DeeBee Accept the answer if it helped you